# Finding a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

So I have an illustrative picture of all of the roots of one complex number (the exponent is random). I have to find this number $z$, if we
know that these roots are on a circle, that's diameter is $3.4$ and degree between the real axis and the positive direction is $-61$ degrees.

Here is the illustrative picture that I have:

[image]

I got the answer that the complex number is $z=0.824+1.487i$.
but all I really need is $a$

Are my calculations right?

Comment: Hint: If you refer to your diagram, $\text{Im(}z)$ is negative, but your solution concludes that the imaginary part is positive.

Comment: Your question is  not clear. Are you searching the number $z$ such that $w^6=z$ with $w=1.7e^{-i\frac{61\pi}{180}}$?

Comment: no, actually $ w^x=z $ this is just illustrative picture that was given to help you understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, we have:
$$w=z^{\frac{1}{6}}=\frac{3.4}{2} \cdot (\cos{(-61)}+i \cdot  \sin{(-61)}) = 0.82418-1.48685i$$
Which is what you have. But this is $w=z^{\frac{1}{6}}$ ;
$$\therefore z = w^6 = 24.00534-2.52306i$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close.

If I take $\sqrt{0.824^2+1.487^2}$, this equals $1.7$, so that checks.

However, if your angle is $-61^{\circ}$, I'd expect the imaginary part to be negative (the angle lies in the fourth quadrant).

You have $\tan ^{-1} 1.487/0.824 = 61^{\circ}$, so the magnitudes are right.

Do you see how to fix it?

That's one of the roots. Now for the other five roots, you add $60^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}, 180^{\circ}, 240^{\circ}, 300^{\circ}$ to the angle.

Comment: I assume  z=0.824-1.487i maybe?

Comment: @Student123 you have the right complex number, but that is **not** $z$ - it is in fact $w$. The points plotted on the graph are the roots of $z$. To get $z$ back you need to raise $w$ to a power. But yes, your answer is correct for $w$.

Comment: is it $z = w^6 = 24.00534-2.52306i$ ?

Answer (score -1):

Change the $+$ to a $-$ and you're golden.

Presumably you have calculated
$$x = 1.7\cos(-61^\circ), y = 1.7\sin(-61^\circ),$$ which does indeed give the answer you suggest.